# How do I get the program to accept a surname of less than 5 characters?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, methods

How do I get the program to accept a surname less than 5 characters for example joe cole would be jcole.

```
public void names(String firstName, String surname) {
    String userIdentity = firstName.substring(0,1) + surname.substring(0,5);
    System.out.println(userIdentity.toLowerCase());
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    UserId name = new UserId();
    String first;
    String last;

    System.out.println("Enter first name: ");
    first = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Enter surname: ");
    last = scan.next();

    name.names(first, last);
    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: the user id would normally be the first letter of the first name and the first 5 letters from the second name

Comment: Please start reading java instead of asking questions.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Math.min(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) to get the lesser value of `5` and the `surname.length()`. Something like,

```
public void names(String firstName, String surname) {
    String userIdentity = firstName.substring(0,1) //
            + surname.substring(0, Math.min(surname.length(), 5));
    System.out.println(userIdentity.toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
String userIdentity = firstName.substring(0,1) + surname.substring(0,5);
```

Only create a substring if the name is long enough.

```
String userIdentity = firstName.substring(0,1) + 
    surname.substring(0,(surname.length >= 5) ? 5 : surname.length);
```